# Grabbing the value of a returned JSON string C#

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have JSON reply and i need to grab "Id" from it. I attempted 2 variations of the code below

```
    using (JsonDocument document = JsonDocument.Parse(jsonstring))
    {

         JsonElement root = document.RootElement;
         JsonElement resultsElement = root.GetProperty("Result");
         List<string> names = new List<string>();

         foreach (var result in resultsElement.EnumerateObject())
         {


               if (result.Value.TryGetProperty("Id", out resultsElement))
               {
                    names.Add(resultsElement.GetString());
               }
         }
   }
```

> The requested operation requires an element of type 'Object', but the target element has type 'Number'.

adjusted EnumerateObject to Enumerate Array but i still get the same error with 'Array' - 'Object' instead of 'Object' - 'Array'

the JSON reply has this format:

```
    {
    "code":1,
    "result":{
        "Id":1,
        "Name":"name"
        }
    }
```

I can't seem to be able to grab the specific Id using the bove method.

Comment: There's no array in this JSON string. It's an object with a `result` property that holds another object

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're making this hard for yourself; it is *much* easier just to map to a type:

```cs
public class MyRoot {
    [JsonProperty("code")]
    public int Code {get;set;}
    [JsonProperty("result")]
    public MyResult Result {get;set;}
}
public class MyResult {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

and use:

```cs
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyRoot>(json);
var result = root.Result;
// etc
```

Answer (score 3):

You can enumerate the parsed `JsonDocument` `Root` element and `result` element. Or do it recursively for every child node that has `JsonValueKind.Object` type and get the `id` value

```cs
using (var document = JsonDocument.Parse(File.ReadAllText("test.json")))
{
    JsonElement root = document.RootElement;
    var names = new List<string>();
    Enumerate(root);

    void Enumerate(JsonElement element)
    {
        if (element.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.Object)
        {
            foreach (var item in element.EnumerateObject())
            {
                if (item.Value.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.Object)
                {
                    Enumerate(item.Value);
                }

                if (item.Value.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.Number && item.Name == "Id")
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine(item.Value.GetRawText());
                    names.Add(item.Value.GetRawText());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code allows you to enumerate JSON with any number of nesting levels